# hdfs data directory "is in an inconsistent state: is incompatible with others."

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Sorry, but this is getting on my nerves...

Exactly when i start loading a table through hive, I start getting this error. And dear old google is not able to help either.

my situation -

1. single node setup. Namenode working properly.
2. datanode startup is failing with this message -

```
ERROR datanode.DataNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /xxxxxx/hadoop/hdfs-data-dir is in an inconsistent state: is incompatible with others.
```

I have already tried to re-format my namenode, but it doesnt help.

Also, I tried to find ways to "format" my datanode, but no success so far..

help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix.
Needed to

1. create a fresh hdfs directory,
2. remove the write permissions from the group (chmod g-w xxxx) and
3. remove all temporary files from /tmp pertaining to hadoop/hdfs.

I am convinced that there could/would be a better/cleaner way to fix this.

still keeping the question open therefore.

Comment: Have you included "hadoop.tmp.dir" property in your "core-site.xml"???It defaults the /tmp directory.So at each restart all the info is lost.

Comment: Makes absolute sense, let me try that tonight. thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Why are you removing write permissions?

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://jvilaikeo.com/?p=72) pointed me at a solution after a drive got reformatted:

> I ran into a problem with hadoop where it wouldn’t startup after I
>   reformatted a drive. To fix this make sure the VERSION number is the
>   same across all hadoop directories
>
> md5sum /hadoop/sd*/dfs/data/current/VERSION
>
> If they aren’t the same version across all partitions, then you will
>   get the error.

I simply copied the VERSION information from one of the other drives, changed permissions, and restarted HDFS.